# C++ Retaining a Lambda Expression in an Object

Tags: c++, lambda

Okay, so I'm writing a simple GUI framework. I stumbled across lambda expressions and thought they'd be a good way to do callbacks. But I can't figure out how to retain the expression in class (very simplified example code below).

```
class class1
{
public:
  class1(auto callback);
private:
  const auto mCallback  
};
class1::class1(auto callback) : mCallback(callback)
{

}
int main()
{
    auto thiscode = [] (int id) 
    {
        std::cout<<"callback from..." << id << std::endl;
    };
    class1 c1 = class1(thiscode);
}
```

I end up with this error,

> error: non-static data member declared 'auto'

Which I suppose makes sense, it can't determine the size at run time. In fact, below C++14 it won't even allow me to pass `auto callback` as a paramter to the constructor. (I think that changed in a readying process for concepts?).

How do I get around this? I don't mind having to do something weird, anything that allows me to retain a reference to the passed lambda expression - I'm golden with.

Comment: Okay - both suggestions are useful, thank you.

Comment: It isn't necessary to mention that this question has been solved. When you  [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that shows what solution helped you and solved your problem. Upvotes can be handed out to any useful answer, even if the answer didn't solve your issue.

Comment: Tas, fair enough. Just me trying to increase the Google-ability. I am gong to try Guillaume Racicot's template solution. I'll accept that answer if it does what I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use std::function to store `thiscode`.

Something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class class1 {
public:
    class1(std::function<void(int)> callback) : mCallback{callback} {};
    void do_callback() { mCallback(3); };
private:
    const std::function<void(int)> mCallback;
};

int main()
{
    auto thiscode = [](int id) {
        std::cout<<"callback from..." << id << std::endl;
    };
    class1 c1 = class1(thiscode);
    c1.do_callback();
    return 0;
}
```

See [live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded7c4dd5272e045).

Answer (score 3):

You can hold them with templates

```
template<typename T>
class class1
{
public:
    class1(T callback): mCallback{std::move(callback)} {}
private:
    const T mCallback  
};

template<typename T>
auto makeClass1(T&& callback) {
    return class1<std::decay_t<T>>{std::forward<T>(callback)};
}

int main()
{
    auto thiscode = [] (int id) 
    {
        std::cout<<"callback from..." << id << std::endl;
    };
    auto c1 = makeClass1(thiscode);
}
```

Or alternatively, you can hold them with [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
class class1
{
public:
  class1(std::function<void(int)> callback);
private:
  const std::function<void(int)> mCallback  
};

int main()
{
    auto thiscode = [] (int id) 
    {
        std::cout<<"callback from..." << id << std::endl;
    };
    class1 c1 = class1(thiscode);
}
```

Comment: I like the template option. It is actually better because the closure will only use as much memory as it needs. With std::function the closure will be allocated on the heap if it is bigger than size that the std::function instantiation needs.

Comment: Yes, this method always allocates on the stack. What I usually do is this method with an abstract class to allow me to a make a list of `class1`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - you'll have to forgive my inexperience with templates here, but if class1 is a base class, would it be as straight forward as making a "make this" function for all the derieved classes? say in the form `classA(T callback, int val);` i.e. for the makeClassA function `return ... std::forward<T>(callback, intvalue);`. Also,  If ClassA's constructor calls class1's constructor do I have to use `mCallback{std::forward<T>(callback)}` to forward the callback?

Comment: oh, I think you misinterpreted my comment. Let's say you have a non template parent class `AbstractClass1`, then `class1` could extend it so you can have a list of `AbstractClass1`. You can't hold an heterogenous list of template of different class without a non template base.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - I'm afraid I'm going to have to go with what `std::functional` provides. I have never managed to grasp how to use templates. Everytime I encounter them it just engrains more fear into me of them. The alternate solution is less flexible, and doesn't quite do what I want. (the callback was meant to be able to be of an arbitary form). But I'm sure I'll be able to find away to work with that. Thanks.

Comment: Template are indeed not easy. But they won't be easier avoiding them ;) templates are a tool. You can use a hammer with your screws, but a screwdriver might be the best for the task! In this case, both template and type easure are good. Templates are a powerful tool. Don't fear them, they are extremely useful from time to time.